# Create a manipulated powerpivot from a powerpivot within the same excel file

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a table added into my data model from SQL server. Now I want to perform some data manipulations to this table and store it into the same data model, besides the original table. How can I achieve this?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few options here.

1. perform the same data extract that you did the first time on the same table but perform your modifications via SQL and/or calculated columns, etc.
2. if you have significant transformations to perform (and if you are utilizing power bi and want to perform this with each refresh or you are wanting to do this as a one-time action), you can utilize Power Query in Excel to either extract the data from the PowerPivot model via a DAX query and import it back in or connect back to the data source and perform the modifications required in Power Query and then import back in to Power Pivot.

Here are a couple of links utilizing a DAX query and/or Power Query to perform the action you require:

http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/implementing-histograms-in-excel-2013-using-dax-query-tables-and-powerpivot/

http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/impleme...nd-powerpivot/